# Irregular pyramids puzzle

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, 3d

I'm working on a 3d framework, especially on a conversion from an exotic coordinate system to the Cartesian one.

So I tried to simplify the problem with a pyramid. Simply, on the figure bellow:

we know EF, the alpha and beta angles only. the angle ABE and EBC are right angles.

And we need to calculate BA, BC and EB.
It's obviously fully constrained, but I don't find the trick. Some help? :D

Thanks in advance.

[image: The pyramid. We know EG, alpha and beta. We look for AB, BC and BE.]

Comment: Is ABC a right angle as well?

Comment: We need to know something about lines AF and CF otherwise the construction is not fully constrained.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that AFCB is a rectangle, we have by the 3D Pythagorean theorem
$$
EF^2 = AB^2 + BC^2 + BE^2
$$
and by trigonometry
$$
AB = BE \tan \alpha \qquad BC = BE \tan \beta \tag{1}
$$
so
$$
EF^2 = BE^2 (\tan^2 \alpha + \tan^2 \beta + 1) \quad \Rightarrow \quad BE = \frac{EF}{\sqrt{\tan^2 \alpha + \tan^2 \beta + 1}}.
$$
Once we know $BE$, $AB$ and $BC$ can be obtained from the trigonometric relationships (1).